# Lock rptdesign file

Tags: security, birt

I am trying to find out if it is possible to lock an rptdesign file.

The idea is to run a report as a service, but without being able to change the default parameters. I know I could just hide the parameter window but still the user could edit the rptdesign file and hard code new values.

Does anyone has any previous experience with this?

Is it possible to make an rptdesign file non-editable?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent users by modifying rptdesign file, you should do it on OS level to enable it only for certain users.

Comment: Hi Kazic, I am not the admin of the system so I am afraid I can't do that. I want to give this report to customers but without letting them modify it. They will run the report against their database and send the report back to me. I know off course that if they want to change something and report false information they could just modify the database....But its more like an open question for the rptdesign files

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that the report is not modified, you can add hidden field storing md5 sum from report file. I mean that this field can store md5sum from your report file on the disk. Then you can compare it with your original sum.

Anyway your problem is slightly different - you are expecting certain data from your customers and you want to be cheated by them. You can use the method with md5sum but it is rather the matter of trust to them here or any other possibility to access to their database than through the report (e.g. they can give you the direct access to the database or you can agree to store this data in your company, not theirs).

Let me know if this answer helps you better.